# Difference between getContinuationToken and getNextContinuationToken in AmazonS3Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I noticed that there was a [getContinuationToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Result.html#getContinuationToken--) method as well as [getNextContinuationToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Result.html#getNextContinuationToken--) on [ListObjectsV2Result](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Result.java). Their description Javadoc is similar in semantic:

> Gets the optional continuation token. Continuation token allows a list to be continued from a specific point. ContinuationToken is provided in truncated list results.

vs

> Gets the optional NextContinuationToken. NextContinuationToken is sent when isTruncated is true meaning there are more keys in the bucket that can be listed. The next list requests to Amazon S3 can be continued by providing this NextContinuationToken.

On the other hand, the list request only has a `setContinuationToken`, but the code example from the [SDK's developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html) shows that it's used by passing it the result of `getNextContinuationToken`. This seems pretty confusing! Does anyone have an idea of why there are two tokens and whether there's a difference between them? I couldn't find good doc about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getContinuationToken` returns token that was used to get *current* result, `getNextContinuationToken` returns token that must be used to get next result.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should have run a request and checked the value, but it was late when I posted that ^^ I still think the doc is not very clear, and naming could have been improved (e.g. `getOriginalContinuationToken` or `getRequestContinuationToken` etc). Thanks :)

Comment: @Dici the Java doc is indeed very unhelpful, but the method names are derived from the XML tags used in the actual API interaction that occurs between the SDK and the service.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

Comment: Right interesting, I noticed the same pattern with the doc of `FilterLogEvents`, where the Javadoc is really lacking but the online one is detailed enough. Perhaps they should not put any Javadoc at all and just reference the online doc, it would be less maintenance for them and less confusing for us. Thanks!